# How to search '(+1)' character substring in a string

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

I want to search for (+1) in a string (which is a GDG dataset name to confirm if it is a GDG) and want to get a binary answer if it has (+1) as part of the string or not. Can some one please help?

Comment: Can you give some input and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like

```
grep -q '+1' file && echo  found
```

Or perhaps

```
[[ $foo =~ '+1' ]] && echo found
```

Comment: @graeme quotes are not needed in the `[[ ]]` construct as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you're right. No word splitting or pathname expansion inside `[[ ]]`, these are what you avoid by using quotes.

Comment: @Graeme exactly, it's about the only place I know where quotes aren't needed so I gleefully left them out and lay waiting for some unsuspecting soul like your good self to attempt an edit :)

Comment: Evil bastard 8-)

Comment: Dammit, and I was just going to add the `-q` at first. I never even noticed it until I was about to hit save. Almost..

Comment: @terdon, not exhaustively, you don't need quotes in variable assignment, or `case $x in ...`

Comment: @glennjackman it just happened to be the one place I was sure of, there may well be others. I'm sure you're right about `case` but you do for variable assignment, at least in bash: `foo=a b` will fail for example.

Comment: Yeah obviously. We were talking about when you don't have to quote variables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the string in a bash variable: `[[ $var == *+1* ]]`